# Unexplained entry in /etc/crypttab

Tags: linux, luks

I'm on Fedora 34 and I have LUKS set up for my main SSD (root fs) and a secondary SSD (VM block device). Recently I was noticing an error during shutdown and it had to do with an unavailable luks device. I tracked this device to my `/etc/crypttab` where it was defined.

```
luks-3470a12d-08fd-4e68-84ce-85f12937d187 UUID=3470a12d-08fd-4e68-84ce-85f12937d187 none discard
luks-6cecd744-b5af-43ce-aa2f-4e8e7068c66f UUID=6cecd744-b5af-43ce-aa2f-4e8e7068c66f /etc/luks-keys/luks-6cecd744-b5af-43ce-aa2f-4e8e7068c66f nofail
luks-d57e12e7-6d14-4a75-b1be-71070282ae88 UUID=d57e12e7-6d14-4a75-b1be-71070282ae88 none nofail
```

The first entry is my root fs, the second entry is the unexplained one, and the third is my secondary SSD. The block device with `UUID=6cecd744-b5af-43ce-aa2f-4e8e7068c66f` does not exist (leading to the error at shutdown), and I have no idea what device it could have possibly been. The keyfile associated with it contains the password used to unlock the other two devices (I know, bad practice).

Is there any explanation to this mysterious block device?

Comment: It is hard to tell because theoretically any configuration tool can edit crypttab file. Probably some tool was confused with disk id and has written erroneous line. Given information you provided I would personally erase that line and forget about this issue.

Comment: @MaximFomin The timestamp on the keyfile is when the system was installed. I used the Fedora installer to set up LUKS for both disk, as to why it made this entry, who knows. I'll just delete it as you said, and update the second disk to use a proper random key/keyfile.